# Web api: 400 bad request

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a web api that works correctly; I've tested it with Postman. However, when make an api call from the client application I get a 400 error. I'm not sure whats going on here. Using Blazor server side
here is the api controller

[HttpPost]

```
    public ActionResult AddEvent([FromBody] BtnData json)
    {



        // BtnData listObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BtnData>(json.ToString());

        string Eve = json.Eve.ToString();//listObj.Eve;
        string DogName = json.DogName.ToString(); //listObj.DogName;
        string time = json.Time.ToString(); //listObj.Time;
        string userid = json.Userid.ToString(); //listObj.Userid;
        string familyid = json.Familyid;
```

}

here's the api call from a Blazor component page in the client application

```
<div class="btn-group-sm">
    <Button class="btn-outline-light btn-sm" @onclick="@Wizz">Wizz</Button>
    <Button class="btn-outline-light btn-sm" @onclick="@Poop">poop </Button>
    <Button class="btn-outline-light btn-sm" @onclick="@Walk">Walk </Button>
    <Button class="btn-outline-light btn-sm" @onclick="@Fetch">Fetch</Button>
    <Button class="btn-outline-light btn-sm" @onclick="@Feed">Feed</Button>
    <Button class="btn-outline-light btn-sm" @onclick="@Bathe">Bathe</Button>



</div>
<br />
<div class="text-center">
    <button class=" btn-outline-success btn-lg" @onclick="@redirect">Save</button>

</div>

@code {

    string id = "1006949";
    string famid = "1006949";
    public void redirect()
    {
        Nav.NavigateTo("Events", true);
        // var httpcontent = new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    }
    public async Task Wizz()
    {

        BtnData Events_ = new BtnData();
        Events_.DogName = _Events.TellDog().ToString();
        Events_.Time = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd hh:mm:ss tt");
        Events_.Eve = "wizz";
        Events_.Familyid = famid.ToString();
        Events_.Userid = id.ToString();

        var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Events_);

        var client = http.CreateClient();
        await client.PostJsonAsync("https://apidoggo.azurewebsites.net/api/Events", json);
        //string userId = "1006949";


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

400 means bad request.

I notice you are now using the default JSon serizalizer (System.Text) on the server but the NewtonSoft one on the client.

So give this a try, just to eliminate JSon incompatibilities :

```
// var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Events_);

   var client = http.CreateClient();
// await client.PostJsonAsync("https://apidoggo.azurewebsites.net/api/Events", json);
   await client.PostAsJsonAsync("https://apidoggo.azurewebsites.net/api/Events", Events_);
```

You may have to add  `using System.Net.Http.Json;` for the extension method.

Comment: I just realized that myself, was coming back to relay the same information! Thank you for your insight!

Comment: Nice find @Henk

Comment: @kjenn31 - don't forget to remove the Newtonsoft package again.

Answer (score 0):

Is the code you pasted here correct? The casing is different between:

Time - time

Familyid - familyid

Userid - userid

Comment: Thanks for you answer, the web api controller is in a different project.

Comment: Yes, but the object "BtnData" should be the same in both projects.